# Rudin Theorem 1.11 "counterexample" (where is my mistake?)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

This is with reference to Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Third Edition by Walter Rudin. The theorem establishes that every ordered set with the least-upper-bound property also has the greatest-lower-bound property.

I understand the general logic and flow of the proof in the book. However, I must have some fundamental misunderstanding of the definitions because I can't find what's wrong with this "counterexample".

$S = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}: x \leq 3 \}$

$B = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}: x^2 < 2 \}$

As far as I can tell, $S$ has the LUB property (the $\sup$ being 3), and $B$ is also bounded below in $S$. However, I don't see how the infimum of $B$ exists in this case.

Maybe it is because $L \notin S$ and this would imply the theorem conditions are not met?

Comment: What is the book? Which edition? Or could you post the theorem?

Comment: Edited the question to include more information.

Comment: $S$ does not have the least upper bound property, which would say that every subset which is bounded above has a supremum.

Comment: Ah, I see, I definitely misunderstood that, thanks! However, I still have some confusion about this concept. In particular, how does it work for the case of example 1.9.b) with the set $Y$ of $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $r < 0$, which the book says it has supremum 0 (and thus the LUB property). Does the set of all the $x \in Y$ such that $x^2 > 2$ have a supremum?

Comment: $Y$ has a supremum, but that has nothing to with whether it has the LUB property. It just says that it has an LUB. Notice that $\mathbb R$ has the LUB property even though it has no LUB.

Comment: Oh, I was confounding the concepts of supremum and having the LUB property. Thanks a lot for your patience and clarification.